# Can i copy an image from my application to mail app in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, copy, paste

I am developing native iOS application.

I have a requirement as copy an image from my application to mail app, how can i accomplish the task kindly suggest me.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 3):

using MFMailComposeViewController

MFMailComposeViewController *mail=[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];

// Determine the file name and extension

NSString *extension =@"png";

NSString * filename=@"email";

// Get the resource path and read the file using NSData

NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:extension];

NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

// Determine the MIME type

```
NSString *mimeType;
if ([extension isEqualToString:@"jpg"]) 
{
    mimeType = @"image/jpeg";
} 
else if ([extension isEqualToString:@"png"])
{
    mimeType = @"image/png";
} 
else if ([extension isEqualToString:@"doc"]) 
{
    mimeType = @"application/msword";
} 
else if ([extension isEqualToString:@"ppt"])
{
    mimeType = @"application/vnd.ms-powerpoint";
} 
else if ([extension isEqualToString:@"html"])
{
    mimeType = @"text/html";
}
else if ([extension isEqualToString:@"pdf"])
{
    mimeType = @"application/pdf";
}
```

// Add attachment

```
[mail addAttachmentData:fileData mimeType:mimeType fileName:filename];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `MFMailComposerController` and use this code:

```
MFMailComposeViewController * mcvc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

mcvc = self;

[mcvc setSubject:@"Subject"];

[mailer setToRecipients:@[@"mail@domain.com"]];

NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mrweb" ofType:@"png"];  
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];  
[mcvc addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"allegato1.png"];

[mcvc setMessageBody:@"Hello bro !" isHTML:NO];

[self presentViewController:mcvc animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

If you have an `UIImage` use

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage.image);
```

to convert `UIImage` in `NSData`.

[Here the complete list of all mime-types](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/mime-types-full).